# two different legends for the same group in geom_line ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot two variables of the same groups, but I need that they are present in two separated legends, one for each variable (solid and dashed line)
Because they share the same group, ggplot is showing them in the same legend.

The code below reproduces my problem.

```
df = data.frame(
  group_ = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
  var1 = c(1:10),
  var2 = c(11:20),
  x_ = c(1:5))


ggplot(data=df , group = a)+
  geom_line(aes(x= x_, y=var1, color= group_))+
  geom_line(aes(x= x_, y=var2, color= group_), lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'b' not found`

Comment: My bad, should be var1, var2, and group_... I fixed the code, Thanks NelsonGon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reshaping your data frame to allow you to set color `aes` to group and linetype `aes` to the variable type.

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars=c("x_", "group_"))

ggplot(data=df2)+
  geom_line(aes(x= x_, y=value, color= group_, lty=variable))
```

[image]